# Unclear return value in Scala function

Tags: scala

This is my Scala function:

```
def combine(occur: Occurrences): List[List[Word]] = {
  if (occur.isEmpty) List(List()) 
  else {
    for {
      combintaion <- combinations(occur)
      words = getWords(combintaion)
      if !words.isEmpty
      word: Word <- words
      rest <- combine(subtract(occur, combintaion))
    } yield List(word) :: rest
  }
}
```

I expect it to return `List[List[Word]]`, but compiler says, that for expression returns `List[List[Object]]`. Why so, and what should I do?

Comment: what does `getWords` return?

Comment: You should change `yield List(word) :: rest` to `yield word :: rest`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change

`yield List(word) :: rest`

to

`yield word :: rest`

since `rest` is type of `List[Word]` and `word :: rest` is still type of `List[Word]`,
hence `for(..) yield word :: rest` is `List[List[Word]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning two type of values here.

Use

```
val result:List[List[Word]]=List()
return result;
```

Insted of

```
if (occur.isEmpty) List(List())
```

because its return type is `List[List[Nothing]]`